# Dual Monitor difficulties (VirtualBox ubuntu host) - rdesktop sessions mirror

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, virtualbox, rdesktop

I am running ubuntu 9.10 host with a Windows guest and need to extend my guest windows desktop into the second monitor (otherwise I will have to convert to a dual boot situation because this is a work furnished computer, please HELP!!)

Current Situation:

Windows Guest Running with VRDP enabled and successfully connecting.
Guest Additions running and VBox set to 2 monitors and I see two monitors in display settings.
connecting via 2 different rdesktop sessions mirrors the display. even though display settings of Guest Windows is set to extend desktop.

is there a rdesktop option to signify to the VBox it is the second display?

I need the second connection be the second display.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried configuring VirtualBox to handle the monitor as if it was double-wide? This would give you one rdesktop window that would span both screens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (commercial) program called TeamViewer that works quite well with multiple monitors. It is free for personal use as well.
Maybe you instead of a second monitor can use a virtual desktop program?

Answer (score 0):

The multi-monitor support in VirtualBox is really intended to be used with the native GUI, not through rdesktop. I would suggest using that mode rather than trying to establish a remote desktop connection. The performance should also improve.

If you have some specific need to use rdesktop in place of the native GUI, I would suggest instead to specify an extra wide connection width (or tall, depending on how your monitors are arranged).